# pandas Series plots wrong inverted datetime axis

Tags: pandas, axis-labels

I have a pandas time series that seems completely normal, but pandas plots it with completely wrong dates and inverted (backwards in time). Any idea why and what to do about it?

```
ds.head()
Out[298]: 
datetime

2008-04-01 08:00:00    5.29

2008-04-02 08:00:00    5.28

2008-04-03 08:00:00    5.27

2008-04-04 08:00:00    5.28

2008-04-05 08:00:00    5.34

Name: grwNAP, dtype: float64

ds.tail()

Out[299]: 

datetime

2016-11-30 02:00:00    5.313735

2016-11-30 04:00:00    5.311754

2016-11-30 06:00:00    5.312812

2016-11-30 08:00:00    5.310735

2016-11-30 10:00:00    5.309754

Name: grwNAP, dtype: float64

type(ds.index)

Out[300]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

[image]

```
ds.plot()

Out[301]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x11aa287f0>

type(ds.index)

Out[303]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex

type(ds)

Out[304]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: That is exactly the plot I would expect if I had a series like yours with one value dated 1707. It's highly likely you have one or more very weird outliers in your index.